# Button to choose among three images

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

What is the best/easiest way to choose an image among three with a button.
It will be a button ( or a label, or anything about 40x40)  that you click to choose an image. I know normally you use a custom picker, but its only for three images, maybe there is a simpler way. ( a tableview?)
the image will be about 50x50 p on the view.
Could someone give the piece of code for it please?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `UISegmentedControl`? You could either use that directly or perhaps present it modally from a button if the space is limited.